# CommType in SymbolInfo returns weird values

Tags: metatrader4

Hi I'm using your dll as in your [RealTimeTicksProvider **example**](https://github.com/Uriil/MetaTrader4.Manager.Wrapper/blob/master/src/P23.MetaTrader4.Manager.Tests/Examples/RealTimeTicksProvider.cs), but the CommType property in symbols is all over the place, for example
1415672933,11,0,24,4

What do these values mean, as they are not consistent with the commtype enum in other classes. Thanks for all your work.

Comment: This value comes from MetaQuotes response. Probably only they will be able to help you understand those numbers

Comment: Yeah I checked your wrapper, you just pass the integer along. no errors there, but I though you might have insight into what the numbers represent. Thanks anyway.